# In Require.js, if require() is a function, how does require.config() exist?

Tags: javascript, function, object, hash, requirejs

This question is more about how javascript objects work in general than Require.js specifically.

Let's say I have a function called `require`:

```
var require = function(){/*cool stuff*/};
```

`require` is not a javascript object.  It does not have a key named "config".  Therefore the notion of `require.config` does not make sense to me.

And yet in Require.js, `require.config` is in fact a function which works.

How is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think `require` is not a JavaScript object?

Comment: Functions in JavaScript **are** objects.

Comment: `f = function() { return "hi!" }; f.g = f; alert(f.g())` - perfectly legit. Another common example of this is jQuery/$: eg. `$(..)` and `$.ajax`.

Comment: _require is not a javascript object. It does not have a key named "config"._ It absolutely __is__, and it absolutely __does__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS just defines a function named `require` and then defines a `config` property on it which has for value a function. A very abridged representation of what it does is something like:

```
require = function () {}
require.config = function () {}
```

This works because, as pointed out already in the comments on your question, functions *are* objects in JavaScript.

Comment: @mareoraft Technically, *strings* are *not* objects (they are primitives that belong to the large value classification) while *Strings* are objects. JavaScript does a good job of applying string->String (eg.) in usage though, which makes methods "callable upon" the string/number/boolean primitive types (when in fact there is an internal promotion/wrapping that occurs).

Comment: Thank you, @user2864740.  Perhaps I should say "As are Strings, and many other Things!"!